# Poppler library for QT4 on windows

Tags: c++, qt4, poppler

I am making a program in which I will include datasheets of PIC processors. I now want to display these inside the QT program itself as a widget. I wanted to use poppler for this, but I am having a very hard time trying to get hold of these binaries! I can't seem to Cmake the poppler for QT4. Could anyone help me on how to make these libraries on Windows 7.

(I have never compiled/build anything yet on Windows, only Unix, I downloaded the CMAKE program, and tried to use this to generate it with the CMakeLists.txt file, but no luck so far.)

The best solution (because this way I could learn it myself, and never have this problem again) is a 'tutorial' on how to do it myself. 
If not then giving me the libraries itself would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd wanted to point you to [SumatraPDF](http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/), but it looks like they're not using poppler any more. You could have a look at the mupdf subdirectory though, it has MSVC makefiles for several libraries required for poppler. You might have some luck adapting them for building libpoppler itself.

You could also use Cygwin or MingW to get/build poppler.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to take a look at this: [Poppler: Displaying PDF Files with Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq27-poppler.html)

Comment: Yes, I have found this, but this explains how to compile it at Unix, and I use Windows. I can't seem to find a guide on how to compile poppler for qt4 on windows (Ive never compiled a program yet on windows, thats the problem). Maybe I'm looking too specific and should I look for a general guide on how to compile on windows.

Comment: @Roy if you download the source code, it has cmake files to build it as part of Qt. Please check that.

Comment: @yasouer, I did this, i downloaded cmake, and then I downloaded all the libraries that it said i needed (zlib, jpeg, libopenjpeg, cairo...). I then pushed configure and generate, which seems to make maps with a makefile in it,and a cmake_install.cmake file? I don't know what to do now with it, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Roy sorry for the very delayed comment. I haven't tried to build it actually. Were you able to get to it? My guess is, I think you can build Poppler along with Qt SDK build.

Comment: @Roy: where you able to build Poppler? I'm struggling with the same problem... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KDEWin installer to automatically get all the appropriate binaries for your machine. This is very useful and is the strategy used in many projects (including my CarMusTy, Carnatic Music Typesetting application).

Check out: http://www.winkde.org/pub/kde/ports/win32/installer/

It automatically downloads all the required dependencies when you ask it download the required binaries. And you can get the dlls suited for your particular compiler. (MSVC, MingW supported)

Also you can get the source code for poppler. KDEWin supports versions, so you can get the latest version binaries or any previous version you like.

Check out http://windows.kde.org/ for more details.

All the best

```
Gopalakrishna Palem
Creator of CFugue and CarMusTy
http://gpalem.web.officelive.com/
```